# Set command in Table Creation in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I found a query not getting actual mean of it, have look.

```
CREATE TABLE pizza_order (
    menu_id     INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    item_name   VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    toppings    SET('Cheese','Sausage','Pepperoni','Ham','Pinapple','Salami') NOT NULL
);
```

Here not getting This "SET" what it mean and what actually it does.

Comment: The manual is a good place to start https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Comment: Here it is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` type in MySQL allows that column to zero or more values. See [11.3.6 The SET Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html).

In this case, the column `toppings` can include any of:

- Cheese
- Sausage
- Pepperoni
- Ham
- Pinapple
- Salami

Though it does the job, it's a very rigid form of storing data. What if you wanted to add toppings dynamically that the developer didn't think of?